# How to use abstraction with ViewBinding with base activity?

Tags: android, generic-programming, abstraction, android-viewbinding

I was making a base class so that all bindings for child will be set in base

I have done till this

```
abstract class BaseActivity2<B : ViewBinding?, T : BaseViewModel?> : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var viewBinding: B? = null
    private var baseViewModel: T? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    }
}
```

but am unable to get a way to bind view in oncreat()
generally we bind layout in view binding as

```
binding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
```

but i am looking for generalized way in base activity

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How using ViewBinding with an abstract base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407823/how-using-viewbinding-with-an-abstract-base-class)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Other answer will also solve problem but I would like to do in a clean way.

My Base Class

```
abstract class BaseVMActivity<VM : ViewModel, B : ViewBinding> : BaseActivity() {

    lateinit var viewModel: VM
    lateinit var binding: B


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this, factory).get(getViewModelClass())
        binding = getViewBinding()
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }

    private fun getViewModelClass(): Class<VM> {
        val type = (javaClass.genericSuperclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0]
        return type as Class<VM>
    }

    abstract fun getViewBinding(): B

}
```

My activity:

```
class MainActivity : BaseVMActivity<AppViewModel, ActivityMainBinding>() {
    override fun getViewBinding() = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
   
}
```

Now I can directly access viewModel or binding:

```
fun dummy(){
        binding.bvReport.text = viewModel.getReportText()
    }
```

Comment: Nice and easy way. Thanks

Comment: can you please do this in JAVA, thanks in advance

Comment: doesn't work with inheritance, e.g. if you have MySecondaryActivity : MainActivity()

Comment: you have to make MainActivity open/abstract and MainActivity<VM : AppViewModel, B : ViewBinding> : BaseVMActivity<AppViewModel, ActivityMainBinding>()

Comment: you'r right @Kibotu. the issue come when we want using different layout and inheritance to other activity class. and why android force me to using the leak inheritance? or any other way to reach it using view binding?

Answer (score 27):

You can declare a lambda property in the constructor to create the binding object

```
abstract class BaseActivity<B : ViewBinding>(val bindingFactory: (LayoutInflater) -> B) : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: B

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = bindingFactory(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)
    }
}
```

You can also define `binding` as lazy property

```
private val binding: B by lazy { bindingFactory(layoutInflater) }
```

Then you need to override nothing in your activities

```
class MainActivity : BaseActivity<ActivityMainBinding>(ActivityMainBinding::inflate)
```

Comment: You can also define `binding` by lazy delegate.

Answer (score 6):

It's cleaner to override binding object getter inside the child activity I think. So:

```
abstract class VBActivity<VB : ViewBinding> : AppCompatActivity() {
  protected abstract val binding: VB

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(binding.root)
  }
}
```

And lets say MainActivity will be something like:

```
class MainActivity : VBActivity<ActivityMainBinding>() {

  override val binding get() = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)

}
```

Comment: if you want to extend MainActivity with different layout, how can i reach it?

view binding can't do it. not prefer using view binding, i guess it