# How to make BaseFragment with View Binding

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, android-jetpack, android-viewbinding

My **BaseFragment**:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<ViewModel : BaseViewModel, Binding : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {

    protected abstract val viewModel: ViewModel
    private var _binding: Binding? = null
    protected val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        _binding = Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false) //This line not working
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        initialize()
        setupListeners()
        observe()
    }

    abstract fun initialize()

    abstract fun setupListeners()

    abstract fun observe()

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
}
```

But this line does not work `_binding = Binding.inflate(inflater, container, false)`

There is a working code but as for me this is shit coding:

```
abstract class BaseFragment<ViewModel : BaseViewModel, T : ViewBinding>() : Fragment() {

    private var _binding:T? = null
    protected abstract val viewModel: ViewModel
    protected val binding get() = _binding!!


    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val superclass: Type = javaClass.genericSuperclass!!
        val aClass = (superclass as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[1] as Class<*>
        try {
            val method: Method = aClass.getDeclaredMethod(
                "inflate",
                LayoutInflater::class.java,
                ViewGroup::class.java,
                Boolean::class.javaPrimitiveType
            )
            _binding = method.invoke(null, layoutInflater, container, false) as T

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initialize()
        setupListeners()
        observe()
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }

    abstract fun initialize()

    abstract fun setupListeners()

    abstract fun observe()
}
```

How to do it right anybody has a clean solution. I know the **DataBinding** has *DataBindingUtil* but i need for **ViewBinding**. Is there something similar for **ViewBinding**

I hope for your answers

.

**EDIT**

**Library:** https://github.com/kirich1409/ViewBindingPropertyDelegate

**BaseFragment:**

```
abstract class BaseFragment<ViewModel : BaseViewModel, Binding : ViewBinding>(
    layoutID: Int
) : Fragment(layoutID) {

    protected abstract val viewModel: ViewModel
    protected abstract val binding: Binding

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        setupViews()
        setupListeners()
        setupObservers()
    }

    abstract fun setupViews()

    abstract fun setupListeners()

    abstract fun setupObservers()
}
```

```
class Fragment : BaseFragment<BaseViewModel, FragmentBinding>(
    R.layout.fragment
) {

    override val viewModel: BaseViewModel by viewModels()
    override val binding: FragmentBinding by viewBinding() // this is from library

    override fun setupViews() {
      
    }

    override fun setupListeners() {

    }

    override fun setupObservers() {
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a parent class for every binding class using View Binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64411049/is-there-a-parent-class-for-every-binding-class-using-view-binding)

Comment: yes I tried it and it works but is it possible to do everything at once in the base fragment

Comment: Hi I have written a blog post completely explaining view binding and have written `baseclass for activity and fragment` checkout [Androidbites|ViewBinding](https://chetangupta.net/viewbinding/)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How using ViewBinding with an abstract base class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62407823/how-using-viewbinding-with-an-abstract-base-class)

Comment: Thanks, but would like a cleaner solution

Comment: Aside from Chetan's comment which is a good one, there are lots of Google results/Github samples for your particular requirement.

Comment: Just don't do this ever and you'll have better code

Answer (score 60):

BaseFragment.kt

```
typealias Inflate<T> = (LayoutInflater, ViewGroup?, Boolean) -> T

abstract class BaseFragment<VB: ViewBinding>(
        private val inflate: Inflate<VB>
) : Fragment() {
    
    private var _binding: VB? = null
    val binding get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = inflate.invoke(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }
```

HomeFragment.kt

```
class HomeFragment() : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>(FragmentHomeBinding::inflate) {

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        binding.homeText.text = "Hello view binding"
    }
}
```

Comment: @Jonny-sz if you have views on BaseFragment how do you access them in HomeFragment?

Comment: @Edalat Feizi Sorry, but i don't understand the question. Please, share example.

Comment: @Jonny-sz, What if my base fragment had a container(having some text views and image views) for showing Error messages? How do we get access to this container view and its children view using this solution?

Comment: @Jay you can implement function in base fragment, eg. showError(String). And this function will do the job of showing error and this function will be available to all child classes. Additionally all child classes has access to the base class fields.

Answer (score 3):

**BaseFragment.kt**

```
abstract class BaseFragment<T : ViewBinding>(private val bindingInflater: (layoutInflater:LayoutInflater) -> T) :
Fragment() {

    // Bindings
    private var _binding: T? = null

    /**
     * Binding
     */
    protected val binding get() = _binding

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        _binding = bindingInflater.invoke(inflater)
        return binding?.root
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        _binding = null
    }


}
```

**HomeFragment.kt**

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>(FragmentHomeBinding::inflate) {

     override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        binding?.txtMsg!!.text = "Hello"
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is my baseViewBinding.

```
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.viewbinding.ViewBinding
import java.lang.reflect.ParameterizedType

/**
 *   author:yxf
 *   time:2021/9/3
 *   BaseBindingFragment
 */
abstract class BaseBindingFragment<VB : ViewBinding> : Fragment() {
    private var _binding : VB? = null
    val binding :VB get() = _binding!!

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val type = javaClass.genericSuperclass
        val clazz = (type as ParameterizedType).actualTypeArguments[0] as Class<VB>
        val method = clazz.getMethod("inflate", LayoutInflater::class.java, ViewGroup::class.java, Boolean::class.java)
        _binding = method.invoke(null, layoutInflater, container, false) as VB
        return _binding!!.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        init()
    }

    abstract fun init()

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        _binding = null
        super.onDestroyView()
    }

}
```

To use

```
class HomeFragment : BaseBindingFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>() {
    override fun init() {
        //TODO() you can use binding in the whole Fragment
    }

}
```

Comment: Ho do you define init() in HomeFragment?

Comment: @SarimAhmed confused. the viewCreate() function contains init(). you just need to implement it

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class BaseFragment<DB : ViewDataBinding> : Fragment(), ViewContract<DB>, BaseConstant {
    private var isRegistered = false
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        if (getLayoutResourceId() != 0) {
            val binding: DB = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, getLayoutResourceId(), container, false)
            binding.setLifecycleOwner { lifecycle}
            onBindData(binding)
            return binding.root
        } else {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("layout resource cannot be null")
        }
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        if (!isRegistered) {
            kotlinBus.register(this)
            isRegistered = true
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        onInitLiveData()
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initView()
        initActionView()
    }

    open fun initView() {
        //TODO init view such as adapter, linearLayoutManager
    }

    open fun initActionView() {
        //TODO init action for view such as onClick
    }
    open fun onInitLiveData(){

    }
    override fun onDetach() {
        super.onDetach()
        if (isRegistered) {
            kotlinBus.unregister(this)
            isRegistered = false
        }
    }


    override fun onBindData(binding: DB) {
        //TODO binding data into layout
    }

}
```

simple ViewContract interface :

```
interface ViewContract<DB> {
    fun getLayoutResourceId(): Int
    fun onBindData(binding: DB)
}
```

and your fragment class could be:

```
class SampleFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentSampleBinding>() {
    private val viewModel by viewModel<HabitsProgressOverallViewModel>()
    @ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
    private val homeViewModel: HomeViewModel by sharedViewModel()
    override fun getLayoutResourceId(): Int {
        return R.layout.fragment_sample
    }

    override fun onBindData(binding: FragmentOverallHabitsCompletionBinding) {
        super.onBindData(binding)
        binding.viewModel = viewModel
    }
}
```

Comment: I need how to do this with ViewBinding not DataBinding